# Python POST form login on website

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to get this login form working in Python with a work site, so I can do some scraping and whatnot with the site data.

Now, when I print the contents of `r.text` it's the same HTML as the login page. No progress is made into the site.

It's also worth mentioning that I'm indifferent about using Requests here. I just find the methods and such from `urllib` to be ugly, and most info I've found on this site has leaned towards using Requests for the above task.

Below is the information I'm working with.

[image]

```
<form action="login.cgi" autocomplete="off" id="frmLogin_4" method="post" name="frmLogin" onsubmit="return Login(1)">
  <input id="tz_offset_5" name="tz_offset" type="hidden">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="table_LoginPage_3">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <input id="realm_16" name="realm" type="hidden" value="All Users">

        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="table_LoginPage_6">
          <tr>
            <td>E-Mail Address</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td><input id="username_5" name="username" size="20" type="text"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Password</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td><input id="password_5" name="password" size="20" type="password"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td><input id="btnSubmit_6" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Sign In">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And below is the Python I'm using at this point.

```
import requests

url = 'https://<scrubbed>/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi'

payload = {
    'username':'<scrubbed>',
    'tz_offset':'-480',
    'realm':'All Users',
    'password':'<scrubbed>',
    'btnSubmit':'Sign In'
}    

session = requests.session()    
r = requests.post(url, payload)
print r.text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `data` keyword.  From the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

> Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML
>   form. To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the data argument. Your
>   dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the request
>   is made:

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
print r.text
```

Additionally, the HTML you posted suggests the form will actually go to `login.cgi` and not `welcome.cgi`. You can see this in the screenshot as well.

Use:

```
url = 'https://<scrubbed>/dana-na/auth/url_default/login.cgi'
```

Comment: Brilliant! Changing from welcome to login.cgi fixed it. Thanks a ton!