# Getting a login page while trying to download a spreadsheet from the url using Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, python-jsonschema

I have written a script that will download a Spreadsheet from the Sharepoint to the folder where the script is run and will update the Spreadsheet. The script was working fine with the given Sharepoint link. When the Sharepoint link is changed and now giving a different url for download although I am getting status code of response header as 200 but instead od downloading the Excel Spreadsheet it is downloading the login page.

Then I have tried opening the url from the Chrome manually.In the chrome also for the first time the login page was displayed from the given url and when the login info is feeded(Username,Password) then automatically file was downloaded and next time when the url is given chrome is downloading the file directly(may be with the help of cookies).

The code that I am using for downloading the file is-

```
import requests, os
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
url="https://securewiki.ith.intel.com/download/attachments"
r=requests.get(url,auth=HttpNtlmAuth('Usrname','password'),verify=False)
with open('Excel.xlsm', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(r.content)
```

How to Provide the login info as I am already authenticating user "HttpNtlmAuth",then why login is asked before downloading and How to provide the login info with the request header in python.

**I have also tried seeing the response header-It is containing something like-Cache-Control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate'**. Is the issue coming because of this??Please tell me how to resolve the issue and provide login in the request header so that file can be downloaded.

I have also tried providing username and password as payload using-

```
payload={'Username':'abc','Password':'xyz'}
requests.get(url,payload=payload,(rest everything same as previous header))
```

**The content type of shown in response header is "text/html"**

But it is also not working.Can somebody please point to error or the solution possible for this.
**NOTE-**
*The link given in question is sample link*

Comment: *is downloading the login page.*: Read [python-post-form-login-on-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031167/python-post-form-login-on-website). Get from the downloaded login page the form data and build the `payload dict` accordingly. It is importand to observe the Answer from the link!

Comment: Login page is very very large in my case.What entries do Ineed to Include in my dict??Maybe the Login information??-@stovfl

Comment: You have to find the `<form>...</form>` that belongs to login. For example: [html-login-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194663/html-login-form-not-functioning). You need all `<input>...</input>` even not visible.

Comment: For every <input>....</input> we have to take "name" as key of dict and "value" as the value of that key in the dict....this is what I understood from the question that you have linked.What about those <input>...</input> that has only "name" field and not "value field"??How to Include them in dict??-@stovfl

Comment: *not "value field"*: Add to the `dict` with empty = `''` value. Doublecheck within your Browsers Sourceview. It's prossible the value got set dynamic from `javascript`, then you are off.

Comment: Getting the same login page even after creating a form in dict for login-@stovfl